# Using SwiftUI ForEach to iterate over [any Protocol] where said protocol is Identifiable

Tags: swift, swiftui

In a ViewModel I have:

```
public var models: [any Tabbable]
```

And Tabbable starts with

```
public protocol Tabbable: Identifiable {
   associatedtype Id
   var id: Id { get }
   /// ...
}
```

In Swift in my ViewModel I can use the Array.forEach to:

```
models.forEach { _ in
   print("Test")
}
```

But in SwiftUI I can't use ForEach to:

```
ForEach(viewModel.models) { _ in
   Text("Test")
}
```

Due to:

> Type 'any Tabbable' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'

Any suggestions?
This is with Swift 5.7. Do I need to go back to making something like AnyTabbable?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: ForEach cannot infer type for ID (I believe error is wrong due to confused compiler) because of double generics. If you use concrete type for id - it works. By the way, in your `forEach` statement nothing of protocol is used, so comparison is not correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider this example in the form of a Playground:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

public protocol Tabbable: Identifiable {
    associatedtype Id
    var id: Id { get }
    
    var name : String { get }
}

struct TabbableA : Tabbable{
    typealias Id = Int
    
    var id : Id = 3
    var name = "TabbableA"
}

struct TabbableB : Tabbable {
    typealias Id = UUID
    
    var id : Id = UUID()
    var name = "TabbableB"
}

struct ViewModel {
    public var models: [any Tabbable]
}

let tabbableA = TabbableA()
let tabbableB = TabbableB()
let models: [any Tabbable] = [tabbableA, tabbableB]

struct ContentView {
    @State var viewModel : ViewModel = ViewModel(models: models)
    
    var body : some View {
        ForEach(viewModel.models) { model in
            Text(model.name)
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, we have the type `TabbableA` where each instance has an `id` property that is an integer (for the sake of the sample they only use "3" but it's the type that is significant).  In `TabbableB` each instance's `id` is a UUID.  Then I create an array where one item is an instance of `TabableA` and another is an instance of `TabbableB`.  The array is of type `[any Tabbable]`.

Then I try to use `ForEach` on the array.  But some elements in the array use `Int` ids and some use `UUID` ids. The system doesn't know what type to use to uniquely identify views. `Ints` and `UUIDs` can't be directly compared to one another to determine equality. While each item that went into the array is `Tabbable`, and therefore conforms to `Identifiable`, the elements coming out of the array, each of which is of type `any Tabbable`, *do not* conform to `Identifiable`. So the system rejects my code.

Another way to think about this: A value whose type is `any SomeProtocol` is a box that can contain anything that conforms to `SomeProtocol`, but the box itself does *not* conform to `SomeProtocol`

Comment: If I want to make the `ID` type specific (i.e. let the compiler know that all elements in `[any Tabbable]` have `ID` of type `UUID`, will this solve this issue? If so, how might I change the code to constraint the `ID` type of `Tabbable` to be `UUID`?

Comment: Here's another thread that reached the same dead end: https://forums.swift.org/t/understanding-the-error-type-any-thing-cannot-conform-to-thing/60810

Comment: @alobaili you could declare `Tabbable` as `public protocol Tabbable: Identifiable where ID == UUID` then change the `ForEach` to `ForEach(viewModel.models, id: \.id)`

Comment: Yes after my comment I continued experimenting and came to the same conclusion. I provided an answer documenting my result. Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: Erasure Pattern is correlated to this problem? Can help to overcome it?

Comment: @Dinox You could use some form of type erasure to get around the issue.  Essentially instead of using the existential provided by the compiler through `any Tabbable` you could substitute your own kind of "box" that had a consistent interface and use that as an interface.  That box would have to have some means of comparing UUIDs and ints in this specific example, but you could do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a KeyPath to the id (or any unique variable): parameter which specifies how to retrieve the `ID` in `ForEach`. It is because all items in `ForEach` must be unique. You can create a structure, which conforms to your protocol. At that moment it should work. The second option is to remove `Identifiable` from the protocol and then you can use that directly.

```
    public protocol Tabbable {
        var id: String { get }
        /// ...
    }
    
    public var models: [Tabbable]

    ForEach(viewModel.models, id: \.id) { _ in
       Text("Test")
    }
```

or

```
    public protocol TabbableType: Identifiable {
        associatedtype Id
        var id: Id { get }
        /// ...
    }

    struct Tabbable: TabbableType {
        var id: String { get }
        /// ...
    }

    public var models: [Tabbable]

    ForEach(viewModel.models) { _ in
       Text("Test")
    }
```

Comment: Which gives the error:
Property 'id' requires that 'Self' be a class type

Which makes me think I need to make an AnyTabbable and do classic type erasure.

Comment: You can create a structure, which conforms to your protocol. At that moment it should work. The second option is to remove `Identifiable` from the protocol and then you can use that directly.

Comment: To use this implementation, you will indeed need to use type erasure or Swift 5.7 will do this automatically for you.

You cannot use your original implementation as the ID type is not guaranteed to be the same, which is needed for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Scott's answer explains very well the reason why the compiler throws that error. I was experimenting with a way to give the compiler the necessary information to make this code compile and found a solution, but it requires adding constraints to your protocol and extending `ForEach`.

you need to constraint the `ID` type of your protocol to a concrete `Hashable` type, like `UUID`. It has very specific syntax. This can be a downside if your use case depends on different types for `ID`.

```swift
protocol Tabbable: Identifiable where ID == UUID {
    var id: Self.ID { get }
}
```

Then you need to extend ForEach and give it an initializer that have all the necessary information to infer the id parameter for you, again, it has very specific syntax:

```swift
extension ForEach where ID == UUID, Content: View, Data.Element == any Tabbable {
    init(_ data: Data, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (any Tabbable) -> Content) {
        self.init(data: id: \.id, content: content)
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to pass a value of type `[any Tabbable]` to a `ForEach` as expected. I don't fully understand why the extension is needed, but without it, the code would not compile unless you pass `id` explicitly when initializing `ForEach`.