# How to conform protocol to Identifiable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have

```
protocol Model: Identifiable where ID == String? {
    var id: Self.ID { get set }
}

struct WidgetModel: Model {
    var id: String?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let models = [any Model]()
    let model : any Model = WidgetModel()
    var body: some View {
        //example 1
        ForEach(models) { _ in
        }
        //example 2
        .sheet(item:model) {
        }
    }
}
```

but gives compiler errors that

> Type 'any Model' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'

According to this discussion the compiler might have a hard time because it doesn't know the type of ID but I specifically told it that it would be String

[Using SwiftUI ForEach to iterate over [any Protocol] where said protocol is Identifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72775116/using-swiftui-foreach-to-iterate-over-any-protocol-where-said-protocol-is-iden)

If this is a swift limitation at this point, how can I work around this? I need to have an array of the protocol because essentially I'm iterating mixed concrete types. I've seen a solution mentioned in that thread where you extend ForEach to get over this but this is not an option because there are plenty of other places where SwiftUI expects an identifiable without allowing you to specify id (.sheet as just one example).

Comment: There is no general "once and for all" solution to this. For `ForEach`, you can do `id: \.id`, but in general, it really depends on what you are doing with `models`.

Comment: @Sweeper I need it to actually conform to identifiable

Comment: Can you show an actual example of your problem? Since you mentioned `sheet`, then show an example of using `sheet` (there might exist a duplicate for this, but I haven't looked), instead of `ForEach`. This will not work in general, as I said, no matter how much you *need* it.

Comment: @Sweeper added sheet example

Comment: Why is `id` optional? The requirement of `Identifiable` is a non-optional `id` property.

Comment: Why not just using `let id = UUID()` and `var id: UUID { get }`?

Comment: Use reference types + inheritance

Comment: @vadian (1) that is absolutely not true and (2) the compile error exists even removing optional

Answer (score 0):

This can help?

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/130177

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class AnyIdentifiable<T>: Identifiable {
    var id: T { _id }
    private let _id: T
    init<U: Identifiable>(_ identifiable: U) where U.ID == T {
        _id = identifiable.id
    }
}
struct WidgetModel: Identifiable {
    var id: String?
}


struct ContentView: View {
    let models = [AnyIdentifiable<String>]()
    @State private var  model: AnyIdentifiable<String?>? = AnyIdentifiable(WidgetModel())
    var body: some View {
        //example 1
        ForEach(models) { _ in
        }
        //example 2
        .sheet(item: $model) { _ in
        }
    }
}
```

Another implementation of erasure pattern is proposed in *Design Patterns with Swift, Florent Vilmart, Giordano Scalzo and Sergio De Simone*
but I don't know if this is the solution for your problem.